# Why is sudo pip install referencing libraries under my user home directory

Tags: python, pip

My impression had been that

```
pip install --user
```

would place the chosen package under the user's home directory. Then why would the following reference the *user* specific directory instead of the system level - e.g. in `/Library/Python` on mac?

To illustrate: let's take a look where the `sudo pip install` looks for the packages:

```
$sudo pip install matplotlib

The directory '/Users/myuser/Library/Caches/pip/http' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and the cache has been disabled. Please check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
The directory '/Users/myuser/Library/Caches/pip' or its parent directory is not owned by the current user and caching wheels has been disabled. check the permissions and owner of that directory. If executing pip with sudo, you may want sudo's -H flag.
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in /Users/myuser/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.1 in /Users/myuser/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from matplotlib)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.7.1 in /Users/myuser/Library/Python/2.7/lib/python/site-packages (from matplotlib)
```

So it is looking under the `/Users/myuser` home directory.. So then what is the mechanism to install under the system `/library` dir ?

Comment: I think this question belongs to Server Fault.

Comment: @xanoetux `pip` is supporting `python` - and sof is about programming. `Server Fault` tends towards networking and sysadmin. While that often includes installation of *system* software it is not so much about installing/configuring *programming* tools.